# Spring Security: The authentication stays after server restart

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, authentication, spring-security

After I restarted Tomcat, I found out the authentication is still there, like I have logged in again. However, after I used `clean tomcat work directory`, the authentication is lost(switched back to `anonymousUser`).

So how does Spring Security remember the authentication between tomcat shutdowns?

What is in the work directory that is related to authentication that was removed?

Is it related to remember-me functionality?

Comment: That has nothing to do wth Spring Security but all with tomcat. If you shutdown tomcat cleanly and have configured that sessions should be flushed to disk the sessions that were active are still active after restart (given that they haven't exceeded their time-to-live). Nothing to do with Spring Security all with your servlet container. Spring Security detects the session and as the `SecurityContext` is stored in the `HttpSession` that is as such restored again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tomcat persists sessions between server restarts. You can change this behavior in [Tomcat configuration](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/manager.html#Disable_Session_Persistence)

From Tomcat docs

> Whenever Apache Tomcat is shut down normally and restarted, or when an
>   application reload is triggered, the standard Manager implementation
>   will attempt to serialize all currently active sessions to a disk file
>   located via the pathname attribute. All such saved sessions will then
>   be deserialized and activated (assuming they have not expired in the
>   mean time) when the application reload is completed.